# Counting number of occurences in already grouped query

Tags: sql

How can I count and order the number of distinct values in a separate column one value in another field has a relation with?

In the example attached, when I run a simple Count & Group By Query, I can get the counts of each occurence. How can I show and count that client_1 appears in both the 'gold' & 'silver' category?

```
select name, category, COUNT(*) 
FROM mytable
GROUP BY name, category
```

gives
[image]

[Data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/df73d/1):

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
   name     VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL 
  ,category VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO mytable(name,category) VALUES ('client_1','gold');
INSERT INTO mytable(name,category) VALUES ('client_1','gold');
INSERT INTO mytable(name,category) VALUES ('client_1','silver');
INSERT INTO mytable(name,category) VALUES ('client_2','silver');
INSERT INTO mytable(name,category) VALUES ('client_3','gold');
INSERT INTO mytable(name,category) VALUES ('client_3','gold');
INSERT INTO mytable(name,category) VALUES ('client_3','gold');
INSERT INTO mytable(name,category) VALUES ('client_4','gold');
```

Comment: I can't read that tiny image text on my laptop. Can you show us the expected result as formatted text?

Comment: The image rather reflects first ordering by catetory, then by name. If you sort as in the question, wouldn't that be precise enough? Otherwise: how would you want to present data? Could imagine conditionally counting gold, silver or bronze clients and have separate columns for. Not having a metal would then result in a 0 value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL [Window Function](https://mode.com/sql-tutorial/sql-window-functions/) to do that.
See the following query as example:

```
SELECT 
   name, 
   category, 
   COUNT(*) as cnt_occurrence,
   COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY name) as cnt_category_for_client
FROM mytable
GROUP BY name, category
```

[VERIFIED RUNNING EXAMPLE SQLFIDDLE LINK](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/df73d/7)

example output:

| name | category | cnt_occurrence | cnt_category_for_client |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| client_1 | gold | 2 | 2 |
| client_1 | silver | 1 | 2 |
| client_2 | silver | 1 | 1 |
| client_3 | gold | 3 | 1 |
| client_4 | gold | 1 | 1 |